# Re-positioning hint text inside EditText after using custom background

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I am using a custom background for my `EditText` but the hint for my textfields don't get aligned properly afterwards.
This is what am getting

[image]

am using a custom background in my `drawable` folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:
          android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:shape="rectangle">

   <stroke
       android:width="8dp"
       android:color="#5647"/>

</shape>
```

and in my `login.xml` file i have :

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_frame"
        android:id="@+id/signInUsernameTextField"
        android:layout_marginTop="209dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_frame"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/signInPasswordTextField"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signInUsernameTextField"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

How do I fix this please ?

Comment: Add your complete layout which contains EditTexts

Comment: Add `android:paddingLeft="15p"` or if you want padding from all sides use `android:padding="15dp"`

Comment: Thanks guys, adding `android:padding="30px"` or `android:paddingLeft="30px"` helped solve the problem.

Comment: Don't use "px" as you will have problems scaling the application on different devices. Instead of "px" you can use "dp".

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_frame"
        android:id="@+id/signInUsernameTextField"
        android:layout_marginTop="209dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_frame"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/signInPasswordTextField"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signInUsernameTextField"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Attached screenshot as output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks...I should just note that when using paddingLeft, paddingRight is also required for `"right-to-left symmetry"`